# Swift: Home Screen Passcode

Tags: ios, swift, lockscreen

Is it possible or is there a way to make an app that automatically do something when the user has entered the wrong passcode in the home screen.? The app should do something only if the passcode is wrong. The passcode I'm talking about are the ones that the user uses to unlock the screen. Only passcode since touchIds are not working on lower versions of iPhones.

If yes, can you give a link on a documentation or maybe even a simple code so I can understand. I'm still a newbie btw. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the previous answer has already said, Apple doesn't allow you to do anything with the passcode. This is because the developer would be able to get the passcode of the user which would be a major security breach.

On a side note, this is possible on jailbroken iOS devices, however that probably misses your point and is against Apple's guidelines anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I'll just use a different approach to run my app, since I as much as possible I want it to run in most iOS devices. Thanks again.

Comment: What would you like to do, maybe there's another way. You could use Touch ID, as this allows you to unlock your app. It isn't what you initially asked but at least something.

Comment: I want to make like a security something app. When a user or someone unlocks the screen but entered the wrong passcode or touchID, the front camera automatically captures a photo and automatically sends it to iCloud, something like that.

Comment: Okay. Something like they have on android if I am not mistaken. Unfortunately or luckily this is not possible on iPhones due to the security restrictions. However, I know from the past that this is possible in Jailbroken devices as such apps exist. I do not recommend jail breaking in any way tough.

Answer (score 1):

No that is not possible. That is an Apple Restriction.

Third party apps cannot have any access information on the home screen passcode actions.